# Awesomium - What is the difference between WebView and WebControl?

Tags: c#, .net, web-controls, awesomium, web-container

Can anyone describe what are the main differences between using WebView and WebControl in Awesomium? In which scenario it's better to use WebView and in which WebControl? What are the pros and cons of using each of these two in WinForms?

Thanks for clarification,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described on their wiki:

> The WebView is mainly used as a windowless web-view component in
>   applications without GUI (Console applications, services etc.)

Basically you'd use `WebControl` where you had a GUI to implement by dropping it on a `Form` or wherever whereas a `WebView` basically does away with the GUI overhead.

I would conclude that under the hood `WebControl` actually uses `WebView` and renders the view to the control surface etc.